# Nancy: Basic module not triggering

Tags: nancy

I think I'm misunderstanding something. I come from the MVC world and is taught that Nancy Modules are Synonymous with Controllers in MVC.

When you first create a new project you get the a basic module like this:

```
public class IndexModule : NancyModule {
    public IndexModule(){
        Get["/"] = parameters => View["index", new ViewModels.IndexModel()];
    }
}
```

Which works fine. But then i wanna create a new module and i go ahead to create this:

```
class HomeModule:NancyModule {
    public HomeModule():base("/home"){ // i saw the "base()" trick in samples
        Get["/"] = p => View["home"];
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work. I get 404 when i access http://localhost:3579/home and the module is not triggered at all. So how does this work and am i even supposed to structure it like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok nevermind i just solved it. I just needed to make the HomeModule class public.

```
public class HomeModule:NancyModule {
    public HomeModule():base("/home"){
        Get["/"] = p => View["home"];
    }
}
```

Comment: I just came across this when I was re factoring a project. The NancyModule that you extend seems to need to be a public class.